# sbt cannot find the scripted-sbt dependency

Tags: sbt

I'm using the `scripted` sbt plugin for one of my projects and it has been working fine, but stopped working sometime recently for no obvious reason. Here is a sample setup that fails:

```
# project/plugins.sbt
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value

# build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

scriptedSettings

# project/build.properties
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

When I do `sbt update` I see the following. Note that it downloads `scripted-plugin` but cannot find `scripted-sbt`. This worked fine until recently and just kind of stopped. Any ideas?

```
test$ sbt update
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /private/tmp/test/project
[info] Updating {file:/private/tmp/test/project/}test-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...

...

[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-plugin/0.13.5/jars/scripted-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#scripted-plugin;0.13.5!scripted-plugin.jar (4424ms)

...

[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/private/tmp/test/)
[info] Updating {file:/private/tmp/test/}test...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt;0.13.5 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt;0.13.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/rnorris/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/scripted-sbt/0.13.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/scripted-sbt/0.13.5/scripted-sbt-0.13.5.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt-launch;0.13.5 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt;0.13.5: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt;0.13.5: not found
  at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
  at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)

...

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt;0.13.5: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 12, 2015 2:13:32 PM
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the scripted plugin is only found in the sbt-plugins repository. Which seems to only be added if [sbtPlugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/9ee8299383afb8c64f175acd9d3cb8648be519b6/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Opts.scala#L56) is set to true.

Making the following change to your example gives me a resolution:

```
#build.sbt 
sbtPlugin := true

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

scriptedSettings
```

With the following output:

```
sbt update
[info] Loading project definition from /root/test/project
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/root/test/)
[info] Updating {file:/root/test/}test...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt-launch;0.13.5 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-sbt/0.13.5/jars/scripted-sbt.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt;0.13.5!scripted-sbt.jar (1323ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/scripted-framework/0.13.5/jars/scripted-framework.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#scripted-framework;0.13.5!scripted-framework.jar (1365ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.5/jars/sbt-launch.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt-launch;0.13.5!sbt-launch.jar (2722ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 11 s, completed Jun 16, 2015 5:45:39 AM
```

Note, I also tried this with sbt 0.13.8 and had the exact same issue and same results.

EDIT: If setting `sbtPlugin := true` doesn't make sense for this particular application, you can add `resolvers += Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")` to the main build.sbt to achieve the same results.

EDIT2: This may also be an issue: [resolvers not shared to dependent sbt projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177799/resolvers-not-shared-to-dependent-sbt-projects)

Comment: The problem was because in `tut` the plugin is a sub-project. But adding this flag at the root "fixed" it. So I'm able to limp along ok now. Thanks!